# How to create a virtual device in android studio on windows 10 platform?

Tags: android, android-studio, virtual-device-manager

I am new to this android studio.I am using Android Studio 2.2 preview 5. 
I created a java file and an xml layout file with no errors.I just wanted to know how does it work. When I am trying to crate a virtual device in AVD manager I faced this problem.
[It is showing to enable VT-x in BIOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzm1x.jpg)

Later I enabled it in BIOS settings.[Image showing Virtual Technology is enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kDzQ.jpg).
I thought some packages would be missing and I installed every package and all the tools available in sdk manager.
Then also I am getting the same error message.
How can I fix this error

Comment: Try submitting a bug report instead by going to `Help > Submit Feedback` then fillup everything and finally click the submit button.

Comment: try to install intelhaxm-android from android sdk , sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager... try again create avd

Comment: You can use other applications like BlueStacks or Genymotion

Comment: Genymotion worked for me.Thanks a lot.